# how to access floating point value from opencv Mat (other than .at and .ptr)

Tags: c++, opencv

```
float data = matrixm.ptr<float>(i)[j]; - working
float data = matrixm.at<float>(i,j); - working
float data = matrixm.data[i*matrixm.step+j*matrix.elemSize()] - is not giving correct output
```

How can we access floating point data directly without using templates (`.at`, `.ptr`)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve? Why do you want to avoid `at<>` and `ptr<>`?

Comment: @Purrfection Using `at<>` to iterate over every pixel in an image is *really* slow. I can't see why there would be an issue with `ptr<>`, particular if you know the image is contiguous(in which case you call it just once).

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast the data (type unsigned char* pointer) pointer to float pointer first:

```
float data = ((float*)matrixm.data)[j+i*matrixm.cols];
```

This works only if the image is contiguous. Or cast it after:

```
float data = (float)(matrix.data[i*matrixm.step[0]+j*matrix.elemSize()]])
```

This works also for conguos images.

For me it doesn t look like a XY problem. It looks like you are new in the world of OpenCV and you wannt to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the functionality of `at<>` without using it?
Here are the interesting src  lines for `at<>`:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1)
    ...
    return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0]*i0))[i1];
```

So you should have:

```
float data = ((float*)(matrixm.data + matrixm.step.p[0]*i))[j];
```

But how does this have *any* advantage over calling `at<>`?

Answer (score 0):

ptr should be the best way (with a good performance); OpenCV doesn't guarantee the Mat would be a continued range on ram, for some large enough image, it can be divided by rows, and save in different location. That's why you need to use ptr to get the location of one row.